how to handle the following message "You need to enable javascript" for csrf-token protected website
I am trying to do replay jmeter script recorded for CSRF-protected website. I did correlation , but its throwing 401 unauthorized error and message reads You need to enable javascript". I do not see anything like Cookie: csrftoken  attributes  in request header or response body in view results tree to proceed further .
Any help in this regards would be highly appreciate

With regards to You need to enable javascript - there is nothing you can do about it, as per JMeter project main page:

JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

When it comes to correlating the token, it doesn't necessarily go as the Cookie, it can come as another Header or it can be present in the response body in form of a hidden HTML input
If you have problems extracting the token from the response you need to share the response with us somehow. If the response contains confidential information I can only suggest taking another look or trying using JMeter Correlation Recorder plugin which is capable of detecting and automatically correlating dynamic parameters
